# What size breaker and wire do I need for a kiln drawing 32 amps at 240 volts?

Tags: electrical

Wiring for a ceramic kiln 32 amps 240 volts

Comment: Where are you on this planet?  Also, is this kiln hardwired or cord-and-plug connected?

Answer (score 4):

You would need a 40A circuit.  (80% of 40A is 32A, that's why the kiln is sized that way).

You would need to run wire large enough for a 40A circuit, i.e. 8 AWG in North America/CO/VZ/PH.